# How to inject componant dependancies inside a service?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I would like to fix some issues and automate some stuff when I create a modal in Ionic V4. The solution I've found is to create a service to create my modals for me.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalSingleton {

   public lock = false;
   public modal: HTMLIonModalElement;

   constructor(
       public toastHelper: ToastHelper,
       public modalController: ModalController,
   ) {
   }

    /**
     * This helper adds a Double click Guard to the modal and implement the progress bar when opening
     * @param $config The modal
     */
   async presentModal( $config: ModalOptions ) {
       if ( this.lock ) {
           console.log('Double click detected');
           return;
       } // Double click guard
       this.lock = true;

       this.toastHelper.presentProgressBar();
       this.modal = await this.modalController.create( $config );

       await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2));
       await this.modal.present();
       this.modal.onDidDismiss().then( onDismiss => {
            this.dismissModal();
       });
       this.toastHelper.dismissProgressBar();
   }


   async dismissModal() {
       this.modal = null;
       this.lock  = false;
   }
```

*Then in my component, I call it.*

> this.modalSingleton.presentModal( {
> component: PaymentMethodModal,
> });

It works but I MUST add "**PaymentMethodModal**" and EVERY other **modal.module** in **app.module.ts**, therefore, losing the lazy loading feature.

How can my service resolve and use modals dynamically?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `PaymentMethodModal` to the  `entryComponents` array inside the containing module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [PaymentMethodModal],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        
        LayoutSharedModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,

        IonicModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [
        AppAuthGuard,
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,   useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
    ],
    exports: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Note: `entryComponents` is [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#entrycomponents-and-analyze_for_entry_components-no-longer-required) since Angular 9, but it can still be used in the case of a library that is consumed by a View Engine application (I don't know how Ionic v4 is implemented). I didn't test this.